# Can't get data from Mysql DB using VueJs

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, vue.js, axios

I tried to get data from mysql db using **vuejs** and **axios** by `{{orderdtls.id}}` in front-end but the data respnose is `null`.
Also I've checked my php code but no problem was found and php code itself separately works fine.

**PHP code :**

```
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With,Origin,Content-Type,Cookie,Accept');
    $Catch_Query = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

 if($Catch_Query->action == 'fetchdata'){
    
              $orderid = $_GET['uniqid'];
              $getorder = "SELECT * FROM ordertbl WHERE uniqid='$orderid'";
              $order_query = $con->query($getorder);
              $order_init = $order_query->fetch_assoc();
              $Order_detalis = array();

              $Order_detalis[] = $order_init;
              echo json_encode($Order_detalis);
           
            }
```

**Vue Script :**

```
var OrderInfo = new Vue({
            el: '#rdp',
            data:{
                orderdtls:'',
            },
            methods:{
                fetchOrderDtls:function(){
                    axios.post(BaseUrl + '/core/core.php', {action:'fetchdata'}).then((response) => {
                        OrderInfo.orderdtls = response.data;
                        console.log(response);
                    }).catch(function(errors){
                        console.log(errors);
                    });
                }
            },
            created(){
                this.fetchOrderDtls();
            }


    });
```

**This is the console log:**

```
{data: "", status: 200, statusText: "", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config: {url: "https://example.com/core/core.php", method: "post", data: "{"action":"fetchdata"}", headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), …}
data: ""
headers: {access-control-allow-headers: "X-Requested-With,Origin,Content-Type,Cookie,Accept", access-control-allow-methods: "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE", access-control-allow-origin: "*", content-length: "0", content-type: "text/html; charset=UTF-8", …}
request: XMLHttpRequest {readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, onreadystatechange: ƒ, …}
status: 200
statusText: ""
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Where is `$_GET['uniqid']` coming from?  That should be undefined

Comment: @Dan It comes from a variable in url like example.com/page.php?uniqid=123

Comment: @Dan The uniqid is shown in page url and i think when php file excuted also the body of the if statement will be excuted and `$orderid` will fill with uniqid.I set the uniq id manually in php file but nothing changed.

Comment: Look again at your Vue code.  There is no `uniqid` in the url you `axios.post` to.  I posted an answer to show you.  When you set manually, what do you see when you `var_dump($order_init)` ?

Comment: @Dan Nothing, even not `NULL` It should be null anyway, I doubt if statement not excuted..

Comment: Start small.  Remove everything from the `if` block except `echo json_encode('test');`

Comment: @Dan It returns nothing with `{{ orderdtls }}` So i've tested it without `if statement` and it works properly.

Comment: I don't see a problem in the `if` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Chat discussion revealed that a 301 redirect was causing the payload not to arrive at the server route.  Answer below is still valid.

---

The code needs to pass a `uniqid` in the data object for the database call.  Also, `$_GET` will be empty since you are doing an axios `post` rather than a `get`.

Pass the `uniqid` along with the other data:

```js
axios.post(BaseUrl + '/core/core.php', {
  action:'fetchdata',
  uniqid: 1                      // <-- Passing the `id` now as well ✅
}).then((response) => {
  OrderInfo.orderdtls = response.data;
  console.log(response);
}).catch(function(errors){
  console.log(errors);
});
```

In the PHP backend, get this `uniqid` from the post data stored from `file_get_contents`:

```php
if($Catch_Query->action == 'fetchdata'){
   $orderid = $Catch_Query->uniqid;
   ...
}
```